# Plot data for each half an hour

Tags: r

I've data as follow:

```
> operation_time      nb_reaction
> 13.02                  14
> 13.08                  4
> 13.58                  17
> 14.02                  36
> 14.09                  44
> 14.52                  64
> 15.03                  78
```

I want to plot (in a barplot) these data x= time and y=nb_reaction, for example by grouping them every 30 min, for example 13.02 and 13.08 will be contained in the same bar, after that the second half hour will contain 13.58 onlyr, after that 14.02 and 14.09 and so on.

How to do so ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question is rather vague, but I would recommend you have a look at the `xts` package. If you have done some tutorials on that, feel welcome to add any concrete questions you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both your columns are numeric you could do:

```
#this function returns the decimal of a number
decimal <- function(x) {

  decs <- as.numeric(substr(format(x,2), 4,5))
  decs

}
```

Then you use the function above to round the time with the following:

```
#Just an ifelse function to round the time to either .00 or .30
df$round_time <- ifelse(decimal(df$operation_time) < 30, 
                        df$operation_time - decimal(df$operation_time) / 100, 
                        df$operation_time - decimal(df$operation_time) / 100 + 0.30)
```

Then you aggregate with the following:

```
toplot <- aggregate(nb_reaction ~ round_time, data=df, FUN=sum)
```

And finally plot:

```
barplot(toplot$nb_reaction, names.arg=as.character(toplot$round_time) )
```

[image]

P.S. You could provide your own labels to names.arg above if you like.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Its is almost what i'm looking for  but in the case of such data it is not ok : i've edited my post to display the results

Comment: There was a small bug with the `decimal` function which I have fixed now. I updated the answer (with your new data set) and this should be ok now :) .

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a lot :)